# Appendix after bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, appendices

I am using `\includefile{}` to add a preliminary literature review to a thesis proposal. The specifications require that "Appendix" be printed in the upper right hand corner. 
I tried ending my proposal main like this:

```
\printbibliography
\rhead{Appendix}
\include{literatureReview}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work. The entire literatureReview file has the header "REFERENCES" in the upper left corner. The proposal main uses a plain page style, and the literatureReview currently has no sections in it. Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

---

EDIT:
Here's a minimal compilable version:

\documentclass{test}

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{someBib}

    %which contains:
    %@Article{TakeuchiKoichi05,
%   author={Takeuchi Koichi and Inui Kentaro and Fujita Atsushi and Takeuchi Nao and Abe Shuya},
%   title={Construction of Compositional Lexical Database Based on {L}exical {C}onceptual {S}tructure},
%   journal={IPSJ SIG Notes},
%   publisher={Information Processing Society of {J}apan (IPSJ)},
%   year={2005},
%   month=sep,
%   volume={2005},
%   number={94},
%   pages={123-130},
%}

\title{A Title}
\author{Nathan Glenn}
\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
\maketitle
%\begin{refsection}


Random citation: \parencite{TakeuchiKoichi05}. 

\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\clearpage
\markboth{Appendix}{}
\begin{refsection}
\include{literatureReview}
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

And here's the class file I used:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2011/5/20 BYU Honors Thesis proposal]

\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespace
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}

\global\let\@course\@empty
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  \begin{flushright}
    \@author\\
    \ifx\@date\@empty
      \today
    \else
      \@date\\
    \fi
  \end{flushright}

  \begin{center}
    \Large{\@title}\\An Honors Thesis Proposal
    \vspace{6 pc}
  \end{center}
}
```

literatureReview.tex has no preamble, and does not change the page styles in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\markboth` command to obtain the desired mark, so you could use

```
\clearpage
\markboth{Appendix}{}
\include{literatureReview}
```

Since you are already loading the `fancyhdr` package, you can add the following lines to the file `literatureReview.tex`:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L,C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{Appendix}
```

Comment: The "REFERENCES" heading is gone, but there is not "Appendix" in the header.

Comment: @Nate Glenn: I've updated my answer with another approach using the `fancyhdr` package.

Comment: Is there anyway to set it back to automatically determining the header based on the chapter title?

Comment: @mangledorf Not sure about what you are asking. Perhaps you can ask a [`follow-up question`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117)? There you can link to this question to provide the background.